# Copy a single file using Robocopy with long path

Tags: powershell

The script below is run from a shortcut in the "Send To" folder. By right-clicking a file and selecting the relevant menu item from the "Send to" menu, the file is copied to a special folder in Documents, then opened in it's default application. It works fine with paths up to 260 characters, but fails if a path exceeds that limit.

I tried to use Robocopy (refer to script), but apparently the long path issue is also affecting Split-Path so I can't get the source folder or file name.

Is there a solution? It doesn't have to use Robocopy. Copied files overwriting older files is okay.

```
#Get the source file path and name
param([string]$SourceFile)

#Shared folder workaround Part 1
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
New-PSDrive -Name source -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\machine1\abc\123 | Out-Null

New-PSDrive -Name target -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\machine2\c$\Logs | Out-Null
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#Create the the destination folder string Part 1  - get the profile's Documents path
[string]$DestinationFolder = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyDocuments")

#Create the the destination folder string Part 2 - add the folder's name to which the file will be copied
$DestinationFolder = "$DestinationFolder\folder to receive the files\" 

#Create the destination folder if it does not exist
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $DestinationFolder

#Copy the source file to the destination folder, quotes added to encapsulate spaces (this fails with long paths)
Copy-Item -Path "$SourceFile" -Destination $DestinationFolder

#Tried using Robocopy but apparently can't get the path or file name due to long file path issue
#Robocopy Split-Path -Path "$SourceFile"  $DestinationFolder Split-Path "$SourceFile" -Leaf

#Shared folder workaround Part 2
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Remove-PSDrive source

Remove-PSDrive target
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#Get the copied file name, quotes added to encapsulate spaces
[string]$NewFile = Split-Path  "$SourceFile" -Leaf

#Add the destination folder to the string
$NewFile = $DestinationFolder +  $NewFile

#Open the copied file
Invoke-Item -Path $NewFile
```

### Edit

As far as I can tell, the very first line of code is the problem.

`param([string]$SourceFile)`

How can I edit this to work with long file names?

Wasif, in the comments below, has suggested I use `\\?\` before `$SourceFile`. I have tried this as in `"\\?\$SourceFile"`, but it does not work. I also tried editing the shortcut property in the SendTo folder. That did not work either.

Comment: Tip: when updating your question, either merge additional material in seamlessly (if not many people have seen it, and you don't have any answers) or add an addendum at the end. Questions get many more future readers than they have had past readers, and so it is best to cater for the future reader - and they will be confused by a question written in reverse chronological order.

Comment: Please liaise with editors in the comments if you want to rollback - you can use their `@name` to ping them. Meta-commentary about how to write/edit questions does not belong in questions, in the same way as meta-commentary about how to write Wikipedia articles does not belong in Wikipedia articles.

Comment: All Meta questions [can be asked on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) (your meta-questions may already have been asked there).

Comment: "Should I ask again in a separate post instead?" - sometimes that is a good idea. I think that if your supplementary question is very tightly bound to the original question, a small update is OK, and then ping an answerer by commenting under their question. Whether the small extra question deserves a new question can be subjective.

Answer (score 1):

You can prefix `\\?\` to make windows API not follow the 260 char limit:

```
$DestinationFolder = "\\?\$($DestinationFolder)\folder to receive the files\"
```

Comment: I think $SourceFile is the problem rather than $DestinationFolder because $DestinationFolder has a relatively short path. If this is true, how and where should I append "\\?\$".

Comment: At the beginning, and `$($SourceFile)` used to concatenate strings and vars. So you need to use `\\?\$($SourceFile)`

Comment: Sorry Wasif, I'm not sure what you mean by "at the beginning". In param([string]$SourceFile), or somewhere else?

Comment: win10 has a setting to enable long file names. [*grin*] do a search for "win10 enable long file names".

Comment: By changing LongPathsEnabled to 1? If so, permission is denied.

Comment: Wasif, I can't get "\\?\" to work. Can you edit my script to show what changes must be made?